# EmberJS Build Failed with no such file or directory for jquery.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ember.js

I have an Ember + Django project that previously worked last week and I have not made a single change since. But now every time I rebuild the project it gives me the following error:

```
Build failed.
The Broccoli Plugin: [SourceMapConcat: Concat: Vendor /assets/vendor.js] failed with:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/IFH/Desktop/planner/planner-frontend/frontend/tmp/source_map_concat-input_base_path-V4BWWQCZ.tmp/0/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.statSync (fs.js:844:18)
    at Concat.keyForFile (/Users/IFH/Desktop/planner/planner-frontend/frontend/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/index.js:87:20)
    at Array.map (native)
    at Concat.CachingWriter._conditionalBuild (/Users/IFH/Desktop/planner/planner-frontend/frontend/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/index.js:109:65)
    at /Users/IFH/Desktop/planner/planner-frontend/frontend/node_modules/broccoli-caching-writer/node_modules/broccoli-plugin/read_compat.js:61:34
    at tryCatch (/Users/IFH/Desktop/planner/planner-frontend/frontend/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:539:12)
    at invokeCallback (/Users/IFH/Desktop/planner/planner-frontend/frontend/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:554:13)
    at publish (/Users/IFH/Desktop/planner/planner-frontend/frontend/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:522:7)
    at flush (/Users/IFH/Desktop/planner/planner-frontend/frontend/node_modules/rsvp/dist/rsvp.js:2414:5)
```

Previously it would create those files in that 'tmp' directory, but now nothing is even being created. Once again, I did not change any file before this error occurred.

Interestingly, `jquery` was present under the `bower_components` directory and was not present under the dependencies in the file `bower.json`. Unfortunately, the issue still persists even after adding `jquery` and the appropriate version to the dependencies under the file `bower.json`.

Please let me know what I should change in order to fix this issue.

Comment: Remove the `dist` and `tmp` folders (`rm -rf dist tmp`), and run `ember s` again. Possible the temp folder has broken files. Recreating the temp folder sometimes fixes such problems.

Comment: Hmmm, I just tried this out and it still does not work.

Comment: check whether jquery is present in the `bower_components` folder of your app. If not, do `rm -rf bower_components && bower install` and try to serve using `ember s`

Comment: That's strange...jquery seems to be present in the bower_components folder. I tried those steps and it still doesn't work...